# Grid View Guide

Tags: flutter

I'm a flutter beginner.

Trying to build something like this..
[Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXGfs.png)

The result I'm getting is:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbOZR.jpg)

The code I wrote:

```
return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: loadedProduct.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => GridItem(
          loadedProduct[i].id,
          loadedProduct[i].title,
          loadedProduct[i].image,
          loadedProduct[i].price,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Grid Items:

```
return Container(
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            offset: Offset(0, 4),
            blurRadius: 20,
            color: Color(0xFFB0CCE1).withOpacity(0.32),
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: GridTile(
        header: GridTileBar(
          title: Text(""),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          child: Image.asset(image),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Please guide what should I have to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now what you are doing is absolutely alright. You just need to add an additional `Column` widget down the image. As you have used an `Expanded` widget , this will cause each of your cards to stretch out vertically and take the shape you want.

Grid Items:

```
return Container(
  height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, 4),
        blurRadius: 20,
        color: Color(0xFFB0CCE1).withOpacity(0.32),
      )
    ],
  ),
  child: GridTile(
    header: GridTileBar(
      title: Text(""),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined, color: Colors.black),
    ),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
      child: Image.asset(image),
    ),
    child: Column(
    /* Add your name , price and a set of radio buttons (for the rating system) with appropriate padding widget (Check this link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) to stretch out each card to the right size*/ 
   ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Great..But I think I forgot to mention that if I remove the padding from inside the container where I placed an image the image gets bigger. And When I add a padding the image gets shrink.. That's the problem and that is something I forgot to mention.. My bad off course. Even I tried to adjust the height and width from inside an image nothing happens..

Comment: Ah , then wrap each image in the `Image` widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) and specify an exact height and width so that it does not change with the containers size. Now , hopefully it should not change the image size when you add or remove padding. If this works , feel free to mark this answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

*You need to use Some more layout `Widgets` to achieve the desired results.*

Please have a look *[at this link.](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)* to know more about `Rows` and `Columns`.

Also see [this Official Document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) for knowing more about `layouts`.